# How to break non text editor content into multiple pages (wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-post-type

So the question basically says it all. I have a custom post type made with a verity of custom fields in it (images, wysiwyg. ect) I am trying to break the post up into multiple pages. For example have the text-editor input appear on one page and the image editor input appear on another page. I have tried using  in a multitude of ways, including inserting a text editor between post types and adding . But none of them have worked and it just displays all the content on one page.

So does anyone know how/if its possible to split custom fields data into multiple pages?

-Note-
Another option I've thought of is just creating different pages for each of the content then hard-linking them. But I don't think it's possible to reference other post data from another post.

Here my single-track.php page currently

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="single-track-storie">
e_title(); ?> </h1>
<?php the_field('content-1'); ?>

</div>
<?php
$img1 = get_field('game_image1');
$img2 = get_field('game_image1');
?>

<img src="<?php echo $img1['url']; ?> " alt="<?php echo $img1['alt']; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $img2['url']; ?> " alt="<?php echo $img2['alt']; ?>">

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: How are you returning the post content? Template code would help.

Comment: Added it, anything else that would help @rnevius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to do this, however none of them are native to WP functions.

**1. You can add a [Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).**

The idea is that you register a shortcode, with what you want to show like `[post-image-stuff]` and then you add that code to your post content and it will load. To paginate, you use `<!––nextpage––>`

Ex:

```
Article content and so on

<!––nextpage––>

[post-image-stuff]
```

This will be your post content, the negative part is that you need to register the shortcodes, but it's not that hard.
I confess I've never tried this, but it should work.

**2. Do you really need to paginate?** Why don't you put a section with Tabs to show the other content? You can put a gallery, a map and author information inside it without the need to reload the page.